# Spectral Unmixing in Google Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I keep getting an error

> L8col.unmix is not a function

Here's the snippet of my code

```
var L8col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterDate(start, end)
            .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
            .filterBounds(aoi)
            //.map(bandrenamel8)
            .map(maskL8sr)
            .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5','B6', 'B7']);
           // .map(bandrename_all);

print(L8col, 'Landsat-8 col');
 



var pine = [0.095,0.134,0.256,0.273,1.911,0.597];
var eucalyptus = [0.141,0.186,0.331,0.373,1.971,0.783];



var fraction = L8col.unmix([pine,eucalyptus]);
Map.addLayer(fraction.clip(aoi), {},'Unmixed Image');
Map.centerObject(L8col,8);
print(fraction);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `.unmix` is to be performed on an `ee.Image` not an `ee.ImageCollection`. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-unmix

For example, `.unmix` is performed on a mean composite of `L8col`:

```
var fraction = L8col.mean().unmix([pine,eucalyptus]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In other way, you can convert it to an image using: `L8col.median()` , `L8col.mosaic()` etc, but also You will get an error because: *“Each endmember must have the same number of values as the input image has bands”*. In your example you select 7 bands but both endmembers (pine,eucalyptus) only has 6 values.